# Colon in file names in Python

Tags: python, windows, filenames, ioerror

As we all know, filenames in Windows can't contain colons.
However, I ran into a problem, that can be reproduced with the following sample code:

```
import os
os.chdir('./temp')
names = ['a', 'b', 'word1: word2', 'c: file', 'd: file']

for name in names:
    with open(name, 'w') as f:
        f.write('foo')
```

This script creates three files in the `./temp` directory: `a`, `b` (with 'foo') and `word1` (empty). It also creates a file named `file` in `D:\`, which is removable storage. It doesn't create anything in `C:\`, which requires administrator rights to write in; however, it does create a file in the current working directory.

I don't understand three things:

1. Why aren't any exceptions thrown (with other forbidden characters, I get IOError)?
2. Why is the `word1` file empty?
3. Why a file is created in the current working directory?

Comment: It's rather tangential to your point (which is a good question), but please use `with` when working with files. Spread good practices!

Comment: `'word1: word2'` stores to the alternate NTFS stream named `' word2'`. Check this with `dir /R word1`.

Comment: `'c: file'` creates a file named `' file'` in the current working directory on the C: drive.

Comment: @eryksun  1 - `0 word1  
          3 word1: word2:$DATA'`  That's interesting, but I still don't quite get what happens. 2- I should add it to question.

Comment: [NTFS Alternate Data Streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29)

Comment: @eryksun Now I got it. When I try to do it on FAT32 drive, i get IOError.

Comment: `:` may be an invalid character in a file _name_, but not in a file _path_, and what you pass to `open` are paths. Just like `/` is invalid in a name, but it's perfctly normal to do `open("/path/to/file")`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Windows NTFS supports file "stream".  You basically append data to a file, outside of the file, and can't be viewed normally.  When you created the file "word1:word2", the hidden stream "word2" is attached to "word1".  If you copied the file word1 to another NTFS machine, the word2 data would come with you

Go here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx and download the streams program.  Running it will show you that word2 is a stream attached to word1

This page also talks about streams:
http://www.forensicfocus.com/dissecting-ntfs-hidden-streams

To really prove this easily, you can use Notepad but you need to use the .txt extension:

```
 file=open('word1.txt:word2.txt','w')
 file.write('Testing streams')
 file.close()
```

Now, using the cmd program, change directories to where you created the files.  Type the following:

```
 c:\tmp> notepad word1.txt
```

You will see an empty file.  Now, try this:

```
 c:\tmp> notepad word1.txt:word2.txt
```

You should see the text `Testing streams`.

Comment: You can also read in the hidden stream with Python: `with open('word1.txt:word2.txt') as f: print f.read()`