# How to make a directory in a directory

Tags: python

I wish to create a directory with relative path.

Here is my code:

```
 if os.path.isdir("Imagettes") is False :
            os.mkdir("Imagettes")
            
        os.makedirs("Imagettes/%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")
```

However it will return an error:

```
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\prunes\lib\os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)

OSError: [WinError 123] The file, directory, or volume name syntax is incorrect: 'Imagettes/%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S'
```

The directory "Imagette" will be correctly created however the date directory I want to create inside won't.
I don't get what's wrong. Can somebody help me find out?

Comment: Are you intending to format the actual date into the name? Also note if you use `makedirs` you don't need to explicitly create `Imagettes/`.

Comment: If the inner directory is ```%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S```, maybe it's because you wrote '/' and not '\' (assuming you are using windows)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried using \ instead of / but it didn't change a thing, the same error occurred. I am indeed working on Windows.

Comment: Colons in path names will cause extremely confusing problems on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25896961/1084416

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A filename cannot contain any of the following characters: `\ / : * ? " < > |`.
So you should replace `:` symbol, for example:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
s = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S")
os.makedirs(f"Imagettes/{s}",exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: Technically a filename can contain a colon on windows but it creates a metadata filestream: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25896961/1084416

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to have it work. I modified my code as follows :

```
if os.path.isdir("Imagettes") is False :
            os.mkdir("Imagettes")
            
today = datetime.now()      
os.mkdir("Imagettes/"+ today.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
```

Hope it can be of use to somebody.